# DOMXpath get from tags with specific text

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

i have something like this:

```
<div class='date'>23/03/12</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='rand2'> text </div>
         <p> text </p>
    </div>
<div class='date'>24/03/12</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <div class='rand2'> text </div>
         <p> text </p>
    </div>
```

I want to take the text inside the div-content which is down(NOT inside) from the div with date 23/03/12
and not with other dates!
Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing! I am new at Xpath and i cant find anything to solve this..

Comment: use the 'next-sibling' xpath operator